# Problem with vue-google-oauth-2 in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-authentication

I am trying to add a Google Sign-In button to my Vue.js application and I found the vue-google-oauth2 plugin. I installed it and followed exactly the `sample.html` code to integrate it in my application, this way:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <h1>Test</h1>
   <button @click="handleClickSignIn" :disabled="!isLoaded">signIn</button>
  </div>
 </template>

 <script>
  /** 
  * You should first need to place these 2 lines of code in your APP ENTRY file, e.g. src/main.js
  *
  * import GAuth from 'vue-google-oauth2'
  * Vue.use(GAuth, {clientId: '4584XXXXXXXX-2gqknkvdjfkdfkvb8uja2k65sldsms7qo9.apps.googleusercontent.com'})
  * 
  */
  export default {
   name: 'test',
   props: [],
   components: {
   },
   data () {
    return {
     isLoaded: false
    }
   },
   computed: {
   },
   methods: {
    handleClickSignIn(){
      this.$gAuth.signIn(function (user) {
         //on success do something
      console.log('user', user)
      }, function (error) {
         //on fail do something
      })
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    let that = this
    let checkGauthLoad = setInterval(function(){
      that.isLoaded = that.$gAuth.isLoaded()
      console.log('checked', that.isLoaded)
      if(that.isLoaded) clearInterval(checkGauthLoad)
    }, 1000);
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that the `isLoaded()` method never returns true, with the Google Chrome console telling me every time I press on the button that the `google api is not ready`, that is the plugin console message printed when the GoogleAuthInstance is `false`. Could anyone help me?

Comment: How does your index.js/main.js look like? Have you initialized the Google Auth? Have you looked at https://github.com/guruahn/vue-google-oauth2#readme?

Comment: I did all those things you asked. I added the two lines in main.js for Google Auth initialization in the project and I also did all the steps presented in the README.md file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isInit` instead of `isLoaded` as the latter will be/is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Add to main.js

```
import GAuth from 'vue-google-oauth2'


Vue.use(GAuth, {
    clientId: '....apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope: 'email',
    prompt: 'consent',
    fetch_basic_profile: true
})


new Vue({
...
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```